# How To Set Session Timeout and Update Database table on timeout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**How to set session timeout ?**

**`destroy session after timeout and want to update database table when session time is over`**

**here is HTML code**
    
    Name:
    Address:
    Street:
    Phone:

```
</form>
**php Code**
<?php
session_start();
//set session timeout
$timeout = 10; 
include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['s1']))
{
    $_SESSION['timeout']=time();
    echo "start time";echo $_SESSION['timeout'];echo "<br>";
    $name=$_POST['t1'];
    $address=$_POST['t2'];
    $street=$_POST['t3'];
    $phone=$_POST['t4'];
//update the query when button is set
    if(!mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE test SET `Name`="Hold1" where `Address`="chd"'))
    {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

}
?>
```

**Then Check the Session timeout with lase session timeout**

```
<?php
**if session is set then run this code**
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['timeout'];
    echo "<br>";
**when time cross the current time destroy the session and update the query**
     $duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];
     echo $duration;echo ">";echo $timeout;
       if($duration > $timeout) 
       {
           header("location:index.php");
            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            **update query when session is destroyed**


if(!mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE test SET `Name`="krishan" where `Address`="chd"'))
        {
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "updated";

        }
           }

    }
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    ?>
```

Comment: your "code" is unpossibly hard to read

Comment: can u please tell me how to update table when session time is over or user click back button .